# Hexadecimal puzzle

Tags: computer-puzzle

Can anyone figure this puzzle out?

Puzzle:

> Shift by 0x83F

Hint 1:

> 8b9 860 8a0 877 8a4 860 8b7 8b3 8b0 89e 8aa 8b6 87e 8af

Hint 2:

> Hint 1 is in UTF-8 in Hex

I was given the puzzle and hints and I know the output is supposed to be a password.

Comment: Are you sure the puzzle is only "Shift by 0x83" and the hint is not *needed* but only augmenting the puzzle??

Answer (score 3):

They all start with an 8, including the shift. Makes me think it's a question of subtraction. If I convert to decimal and subtract the 0x83F (i.e. 2111<sub>10</sub>) from each of the digits, I get

> z!a8e!xtq_kw?p

which is not only UTF-8, it's entirely ASCII.

Can you confirm this password works?